# how to auto-install dependencies for custom made r-package

Tags: r, dependencies, r-package, cran

I am currently working on a r-package. I would like to submit my r package to CRAN, but I have a question regarding dependency installations on CRAN.

I have almost finished my package, added the required dependencies to the NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files as Imports, and get no errors or warnings

when running the check in Rstudio. The package runs on the pc, where I´ve built the package, but when I install the package on a pc, where the dependencies

are not preinstalled, I get the following error:

ERROR:

```
dependencies 'depth', 'geometry' are not available for package 'packagename'
* removing 'C:/Users/156932/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.2.1/library/packagename'
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘packagename’ had non-zero exit status
```

The problem is that a local installation of my package (via USB-stick for example) can´t install the dependencies from CRAN.

The package works perfectly fine, if the dependencies are preinstalled.

Now I don´t want to submit my package to CRAN if the end user gets the same error message when installing my package.

Question: After I submit my package to CRAN, will CRAN install dependencies automatically (via "install.packages()"), resolving the issue I have right now?

Or do I have to modify the R-package or the Description-file to make sure my Package can install dependencies?

I provided the dependencies to the NAMESPACE-file as @ImportFrom via the devtools::document()-function. I added the dependencies to the DESCRIPTION-file via `usethis::use_package("x",type="Imports")`.
The Description looks like this:

```
License: GPL (>= 3)
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.2.3
Imports: 
    depth,
    geometry,
    graphics,
    grDevices,
    MASS,
    mvtnorm,
    nlme,
    rgl,
    stats
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  You may want to look into formating a post to make it more legible, we often use 'code' for code segments.  In short, yes, `install.packages()` will by defaul install dependencies, and those are resolved from 'known' repositories which is CRAN and BioConductors, generally.  You can have 'Suggests:'-only from 'Additional_repositories' too.  All this in the _Writing R Extensions_ manual and often discussed on the friendly r-package-devel list (or here in older questions you can search too).

Comment: thanks, so if i submit my package and install it on a different pc from CRAN, the dependencies will be installed automatically, right? I dont use any dependencies which arent available on CRAN.

Comment: How are you installing the packages in the case when you are getting the error? Are you using `install.packages()` with `repos=NULL`? Because that prevents the installation from downloading anything from CRAN.

Comment: @MrFlick I use the "install" button under the "packages"-window in RStudio. A popup-window appears and I chose **"Install from: Package Archive File (zip tar.gz)"**. I choose the Package Archive and install the package.

Comment: @MrFlick I also don´t want to use that Installation-method in the future. I was wondering what will happen if someone uses the default    install.packages()    function to download my package from CRAn after Submission. Will they have the same error-message or will cease being a problem? I am not sure how CRAN tells its System to download missing dependencies from the **DESCRIPTION-File** of a package. Does CRAn have a system to scan my package to tell RStudio what dependencies are missing on the System or do I need to add something to the DESCRIPTION-File?

Comment: Your DESCRIPTION file needs to list all dependencies. When installing packages from CRAN, the default is to automatically install all dependencies as well (that is different than the default for installing from a package archive file). So everything looks like it should be fine when deployed to CRAN because CRAN does read the DESCRIPTION file.